# Kibana dashboard is not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana

I have installed Kibana on Ubuntu.

When I checked the status using the command `systemctl status kibana`, it says that the status is active. But when I access it using the url, it is not accessible.

Comment: Do you have security group allow for 5601 and can you access from localhost?

Comment: Security group port 5601 is open.

Comment: Be more specific. When you access the url, what is the exact error you get?

Comment: In addition to the above follow-up question, it is necessary to understand what is the URL you are using to access the server? is it a remote server or local? Please add more info so we can assist.